# Arduino - Strange behavior converting HEX to RGB

Tags: arduino, hex, rgb

I'm trying to convert a HEX color code to RGB but when I run the code on Arduino, it doesn't pick up the RED.

Am I doing something wrong?

On a C++ compilator works just fine.

```
void setup() {

    Serial.begin(115200);

    String hexstring = "B787B7";
    int number = (int) strtol( &hexstring[1], NULL, 16);
    int r = number >> 16;
    int g = number >> 8 & 0xFF;
    int b = number & 0xFF;

    Serial.print("red is ");
    Serial.println(r);
    Serial.print("green is ");
    Serial.println(g);
    Serial.print("blue is ");
    Serial.println(b);

}

void loop() {

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `number` should be of type `long` as type `int` is coded on 16 bits and cannot take value above 32,767.

```
void setup() {

    Serial.begin(115200);

    String hexstring = "B787B7";
    long number = (long) strtol( &hexstring[1], NULL, 16);
    int r = number >> 16;
    int g = number >> 8 & 0xFF;
    int b = number & 0xFF;

    Serial.print("red is ");
    Serial.println(r);
    Serial.print("green is ");
    Serial.println(g);
    Serial.print("blue is ");
    Serial.println(b);

}

void loop() {

}
```

Answer (score 10):

When I ran your code I still was not picking up red's value.
However using MAC's same code

```
long number = (long) strtol( &hexstring[1], NULL, 16 );
```

to

```
long number = (long) strtol( &hexstring[0], NULL, 16 );
```

I hope this helps someone struggling with RGB and HEX values

Comment: yep, for this example it has to start with 0, instead of 1. If you use a string like #ff0000 you have to start at position 1 to ignore the # in front of the string :)